# Conflict between thousand separator and date format - pandas.read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a problem with reading data from csv file with Pythons' read_csv method.

Row format:

```
'06.02.2013;544,00;2,52;3,53'
```

With this implementation:

```
 df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";", header=5, decimal=",")
 df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)
```

Python gives me an error: **invalid literal for int() with base 10: '544,00'**,
When I print this dataframe object I can see that some float values have been recognized and some haven't.

```
                value   value1  value2
Datum                               
06.02.2013      544,00   2.52    3.53
```

What I did next was implement a method (even though I do not have thousands in my file):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";", header=5, decimal=",", thousands = ".")
```

Then I do not get that error, but resulting date is **06022013 instead of 06.02.2013**.

To solve that problem, I have tried this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";", header=5, dayfirst=True, decimal=",", thousands = ".", parse_dates=[0])
```

In that case, date is formatted like this: *January 2, 2013, midnight.*

And after all of that I have tried to add a **date_parser** to this method like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";", header=5, dayfirst=True, decimal=",", thousands = ".", parse_dates=[0],date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y') )
```

But it still formatted date like before: *January 2, 2013, midnight*.
Has anyone else encountered such a problem or knows how to solve it?

EDIT:
So, the real data looks like this (first row after header):

```
0
1
2
3
4
Datum       value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7 value8 value9 value10 value11 value12 value13 value14
01.03.2020    str1  str2   str3   str4   str5   str6   9,82   9,75   0,75   500,00  544,00  44,00   50,00  49,25

In [1]: df['value11'] = df['value11'].astype(int)
Out [1]: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '544,00'
```

Also, error takes place already on first row. I have since come to realize that after changing first row, I get no error. Modified first row:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Datum      value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7 value8 value9 value10 value11 value12 value13 value14
01.04.2020    str1  str2   str3   str4   str5   str6   36,03   5,46   84,85   23,00  64,00  41,00   59,92  -24,92
```

Pandas version: 1.0.2

EDIT2:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";", header=5, decimal=",")
print(df.iloc[:,7:])
```

OUTPUT:
[image: **Headers not included because of information sensitivity**]

EDIT3:
I found out how to reproduce this problem. Example of csv file:

```
data.csv
0
1
2
3
4
Datum
Datum;value1;value2;value3;value4;value5;value6;value7;value8;value9;value10;value11;value12;value13;value14
01.03.2020;str1;str2;str3;str4;str5;str6;"9,82";"9,75";"0,75";"500,00";"544,00";"44,00";"50,00";"49,25"
01.03.2020;str1;str2;str3;str4;str5;str6;"9,72";"7,00";"27,97";"737,00";"1.123,00";"386,00";"51,03";"23,06"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Why are you setting `header=5`? Isn't your header on the first row?

Comment: I edited the post with additional information so I deleted my previous comments. And yes, the header is really 5, starting from 0. Sorry for not mentioning that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";", header=5, decimal=",", thousands = ".", parse_dates=['Datum'], date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))
df['Datum'] = df['Datum'].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

Problem was because thousands separator was ".", I somehow managed to format the date like I wanted afterwards and now everything works good.

Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you indicating you header row correctly?

Here's a sample CSV:

```
cat seven_rows.csv                                                                                                                                                                                  

0
1
2
3
4
Datum;value1;value2;value3;value4;value5;value6;value7;value8;value9;value10;value11;value12;value13;value14
01.03.2020;str1;str2;str3;str4;str5;str6;9,82;9,75;0,75;500,00;544,00;44,00;50,00;49,25
```

Your original import:

```
df = pd.read_csv('seven_rows.csv', sep=";", header=5, decimal=",")

        Datum value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6  value7  value8  value9  value10  value11  value12  value13  value14
0  01.03.2020   str1   str2   str3   str4   str5   str6    9.82    9.75    0.75    500.0      544.0     44.0     50.0    49.25
```

Casting `value11` to `int`:

```
df['value11'] = df['value11'].astype(int)

        Datum value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6  value7  value8  value9  value10  value11  value12  value13  value14
0  01.03.2020   str1   str2   str3   str4   str5   str6    9.82    9.75    0.75    500.0      544     44.0     50.0    49.25
```

Comment: I can reproduce your error if I replace the comma with a comma-like non-ASCII character, like [low qoute](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201A). Please verify your file contains only the characters you intend.

Comment: I have edited my first post again, there you can see the output after reading csv file. Some floats are recognized and some are not. I am using ";" as a separator.

Comment: Guys, I figured out how to reproduce this problem. Example is in EDIT3 in my post. Thanks for all help so far!